# Server Error in '/' Application. How do I fix linking error?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created my code, everything works except for the one link that I try to go to. The file is created, the file has code in it, yet, it just does not want to open it when I debug my code.

Requested URL: /Students/Login

```
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Students", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
```

[image: File is created]

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Create", "Students", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Students", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: When you debug - at which point does it break?

Comment: Whenever I click the link in my navbar to go to the login page - but it doesn't really break, it just throws out that it can't the file that is actually there.

Comment: Thre must be a stacktrace in the debug window or the console, whereever it outputs to

Comment: But yeah that's the thing, it gives no errors, I just checked the Output console for debug, and it doesn't even throw out an error. This is just a case where the link to the file just does not register that the file exists.

Comment: Can you share the code, so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've edited it into the main post.

Comment: If you can a git repo but we perfect. If that is not feasible, your Students page including code, as well as your layout file would be enough too. I don't think the error will be in a simple link.

Comment: Hey, I managed to fix it. Thanks for commenting and trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find and fix the error I was having myself.

I forgot to add the page' action result in the controller.

Fix:

```
// GET: Students/Login
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Students/Login
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "ID,Username,Password,ConfirmPassword")] Students students)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Students.Add(students);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(students);
}
```